# how to use reinterpret_cast to cast to a derived class pointer in c++

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast

Here is my test example:

```
struct base {
    virtual ~base(){}
    int x;
};

struct derived: public virtual base {
    base * clone() {
        return new derived;
    }
    derived(): s("a") {}
    std::string s;
};

int main () {
    derived d;
    base * b = d.clone();
    derived * t = reinterpret_cast<derived*>(b);
    std::cout << t->s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It crashes at the line where I print s. Since "b" is a pointer to the derived class, reinterpret_cast should just work. I wonder why it crashes. At the same time, if I replace reinterpret_cast with dynamic_cast, then it works.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Even if `b` is here *dynamically* of type `derived`, you have to use `dynamic_cast`. This is what  `dynamic_cast` is for, to dynamically convert a pointer of a base class into a derived class at runtime.

`reinterpret_cast` takes the raw pointer and considers it as being of the derived type. However, because of the `virtual` inheritance, a slight adjustment must be done to the pointer to point to the correct method dispatch table, and that's precisely what `dynamic_cast` will do.

Comment: Weren't for the virtual inheritance, `static_cast` would have worked. There is no need to go runtime when you know for sure your base is a derived.

Comment: Yes, you are right, if I remove _virtual_ and make it just struct derived: public base, then reinterpret_cast works too (at least, there are no crashes)

Comment: K-ballo: you know, the ugly rules of inheritance when building libraries (you don't know if in the future a class will be inherited via two paths) force you to sometimes abuse virtual inheritance just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Don't `reinterpret_cast` it, it will cause trouble with multiple or virtual inheritance, like in your case. Wont a simply `static_cast` do the job here?

To know why, search for implementations of virtual inheritance. A common one is to store a pointer to the base class within the object, so the virtual base does not share the same address than its derived classes. There is a similar case when multiple inheritance is used.

In short, `reinterpret_cast` can't do much more than casting pointers to ints and back (if there is enough size in the int to contain a pointer).

Comment: In this case compiler says that
    error: cannot convert from base 'base' to derived type 'derived' via virtual base 'base'

Comment: You cannot statically cast from a virtual base. So you have to `dynamic_cast` here (which implies runtime penalties). Besides that, I agree that `reinterpret_cast` is **evil**!

Comment: Then you should go with `dynamic_cast` instead.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers here suggested, you cannot use `reinterpret_cast` in this fashion because the *value of the pointer* to `base` actually differs from the *value of the pointer* to `derived`. The valid pointer is deduced at runtime which is why you have to use `dynamic_cast`. `static_cast` **cannot** work, as you don't know at designtime through which intermediate type the most derived class (the one you want to cast to) was derived from the type you have a pointer to.

The real question here should be: I know at design time, how to compute the `derived` pointer from the `base` pointer. How can the runtime penalty (of `dynamic_cast`) be avoided?

Frankly, I don't see a really good option here, but a *possible* option is to store the pointer to the most derived type in a constant pointer inside the root class, like so:

```
struct base {
  void* const self;
  virtual ~base() {}
  protected:
    base(void* self) : self(self) {}
};
struct derived : public virtual base {
  derived() : base(this) {}
}
```

This is ugly and dangerous, because it sacrifices type safety for performance (if you are really lucky, you get a *slight* runtime performance out of it). But you will be able to `reinterpret_cast` your `base` pointer (the `self` member of type `void*`) into a `derived` pointer.